Where is multiplier in posterior distribution of Bayesian linear regression's parameter?
I've recently studied Bayesian linear regression from lecture's notes on CS229 Summer edition 2019 course (https://cs229.stanford.edu/summer2019/gaussian_processes.pdf). There is a posterior distribution of $\theta$ given $S = \{x^{(i)}, y^{(i)}\}$ written out as
$$
p(\theta ~|~ S) = 
\frac{p(\theta) p(S ~|~ \theta)}{\int_{\theta'} p(\theta') p(S ~|~ \theta') d\theta'} =
\frac{p(\theta) \prod_{i=1}^n p(y^{(i)} ~|~ x^{(i)}, \theta)}
{\int_{\theta'} p(\theta') \prod_{i=1}^n p(y^{(i)} ~|~ x^{(i)}, \theta') d\theta'}.
$$
But as I started to get the expression by myself I got
$$
p(\theta ~|~ S) = 
\frac{p(\theta) p(S ~|~ \theta)}{\int_{\theta'} p(\theta') p(S ~|~ \theta') d\theta'} =
\frac{p(\theta) \prod_{i=1}^n p(x^{(i)}, y^{(i)} ~|~ \theta)}
{\int_{\theta'} p(\theta') \prod_{i=1}^n p(x^{(i)}, y^{(i)} ~|~ \theta') d\theta'} =
\frac{p(\theta) \prod_{i=1}^n p(y^{(i)} ~|~ x^{(i)}, \theta) p(x^{(i)} ~|~ \theta)}
{\int_{\theta'} p(\theta') \prod_{i=1}^n p(y^{(i)} ~|~ x^{(i)}, \theta') p(x^{(i)} ~|~ \theta') d\theta'}.
$$
How can we get rid of $p(x^{(i)} ~|~ \theta)$ and $p(x^{(i)} ~|~ \theta')$ multipliers to get expression as in lecture's notes?


Most common situation:
In "typical" regression setting, we only model the conditional distribution of responses $y^{(i)}$ given regressors $x^{(i)}$, and the marginal distribution of regressors is not of interest and is left unmodeled.
In other words, we may treat $x^{(i)}$ as constant values (or having been conditioned upon). In this case, there will be no $p\left(x^{(i)} \mid \theta\right)$ factor at all.

Less common situation:
Even if we model $x^{(i)}$, but as long as the  $x^{(i)}$ model is free of regression parameters $\theta$ (that is involved in the conditional distribution), $p\left(x^{(i)} \mid \theta\right) \propto f\left( x^{(i)}\right)$ for some function $f$, free of $\theta$. Thus, they can be safely cancelled out.

Rare situation:
Extremely rarely will we model  $x^{(i)}$ with shared parameters between $x^{(i)}$ and $y^{(i)} \mid x^{(i)}$. In this case, your derivation applies.


